# Is the STTH108 diode a suitable alternative for the STTH1L06?

Tags: diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, boost, rectifier

The applied boost rectifier diode in the PFC converter shown below is an STTH1L06, but I used an STTH108, thinking that it has a higher voltage rate.

There was no problem in no-load mode, but strong sparks occurred between the cathode and the anode of this diode for a small amount of load as I increased the voltage to 30-40 V and I quickly cut off the input. Is this diode not the right choice or is the problem from somewhere else?

The switching frequency is variable during a line cycle and is about 200 kHz. The NTC is conducting and undamaged. The gap between SMD pads is about 2 mm. A photo is attached; the diode is adjacent to the MOSFET. The signs of arcing between pads is visible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use the DO41 or the SMA variant? Arcing around the DO41 case in this circuit let me assume a contaminated diode surface. If the diode is clean, you might need a snubber network at the Drain of Q1. Is the voltage regulation operating?

Comment: @Jens I used the SMA. When I increased the voltage to 30-40 volts, strong sparks occurred and I quickly cut off the input. it wasn't a minor sparking

Comment: Did you accidentially use the wrong diode polarity? This would be an explanation for high voltage gradients there (and no output voltage).

Comment: @Jens the polarity was correct. According to the features mentioned in the data sheet of STTH108 and STTH1L06, I think it's not suitable for ultrafast switching applications. Is it?

Comment: Both diodes are not optimal here, but this does not explain arcing. Is the NTC conducting? What is the switching frequency?

Comment: What is the gap between the SMD pad of the diode and the surrounding copper area?

Comment: @Jens the switching frequency is variable during a line cycle and it is about 200kHz. The NTC is conducting and undamaged. The gap between smd pads is about 2mm. A photo is attached. Diode is adjacent to the mosfet. The signs of arcing between pads is visible.

Comment: The board needs proper cleaning (ethanol, fat solvent, then hot air). Add a series snubber network 100 pF / 1 kV and 100 ohm parallel to the diode.